# Searchbox for Custom Listview with text and images

Tags: android, image, listview, search

Hello, Everybody. I've created a Listview with images, text and searchbox. 
This is my code: java and layout. So, I need some help. I don't know how to do my searchbox starts to work. I need a code.

My MainActivity.java

```
package android.codigos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.codigos.objetos.ItemListView;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private EditText ed;
private AdapterListView adapterListView;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Pega a referencia do ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    //Define o Listener quando alguem clicar no item.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    createListView();
}

private void createListView() {
    //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
    itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();
    ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Bahia", R.drawable.bahia);
    ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Minas Gerais", R.drawable.minasgerais);
    ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Rio de Janeiro", R.drawable.riodejaneiro);
    ItemListView item4 = new ItemListView("São Paulo", R.drawable.saopaulo);

    itens.add(item1);
    itens.add(item2);
    itens.add(item3);
    itens.add(item4);

    //Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    //Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    //Cor quando a lista Ã© selecionada para rolagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    //DemostraÃ§Ã£o
    Toast.makeText(this, "Você Clicou em: " + item.getTexto(),    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

AdapterListView.java

```
package android.codigos;

import android.codigos.objetos.ItemListView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
*
*/
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public ItemListView getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementaÃ§Ã£o
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posÃ§Ã£o.
    ItemListView item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atravez do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informaÃ§Ãµes.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());

    return view;
}
```

}

ItemListView.java

```
package android.codigos.objetos;

/**
*
*/
public class ItemListView {

private String texto;
private int iconeRid;

public ItemListView() {
}

public ItemListView(String texto, int iconeRid) {
    this.texto = texto;
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public int getIconeRid() {
    return iconeRid;
}

public void setIconeRid(int iconeRid) {
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}
```

}

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
>    

    <EditText
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Type here to search."
>

</EditText>


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#ECECEC"
    android:dividerHeight="1sp"
    />    
</LinearLayout>
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the algorithm is the following:

1. Take a text from EditText.
2. Remove all items that don't match the search query from your ArrayList.
3. Refresh your adapter with methods adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

If you need an example of a source code, I can attach it.

Comment: So, what should I put in search_box.xml?

Comment: Don't worry, Vetal :)! Hey, could you clarify your code? Because I don't know java so well. For example, what should I put in "search_box.xml"? Should I create a EditText field? If you've noticed I've created um EditTex on "main.xml" layout. There is a ListView activity and SearchBox. So, It's not easier if I use a "textwatcher" in MainActivity.java?

Comment: It would better if you put the entire code and its changes here. I'll appreciate you so much!!! :)

Comment: Yeah, I woud like to an example of a source code :) Thanks Vetal... my e-mail: gulivernashuatec@gmail.com

Comment: @user1550421 To use search functionality you have to implement addTextChangeListener() for the EditText.Take a look at this post http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html